# Geopandas and significant digits of coords

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, geopandas

I trying to put coords of a points GDF in 2 columns. But i'm a little bit surprised by result. In geometry all points have 6 significant digits but in columns only 5 (rounded)...

My code to put coords in columns:

```
src['LONGITUDE'] = src.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.x)
src['LATITUDE'] = src.geometry.apply(lambda p: p.y)
```

GDF head :

```
            DATE_heure   LONGITUDE   LATITUDE  ALTITUDE  OR_MAG_GPS  V_DOP  \
0  2018-01-11 21:40:54 -122.430177  38.559796    516.02      224.04   1.47   
1  2018-01-11 21:29:31 -122.429779  38.560371    519.50      282.03   1.05   
2  2018-01-11 21:29:32 -122.429778  38.560372    519.25      282.03   1.19   
3  2018-01-11 21:29:33 -122.429780  38.560370    519.19      279.01   1.13   

P_DOP  VOL_PAR_H  VITESSE_AV  SARMENT_0_  ...   SARMENT_43  SARMENT_44  \
0   1.94        0.0        3.13       8.906  ...        0.000       0.000   
1   1.32        0.0        0.07      13.336  ...       14.368      25.403   
2   1.43        0.0        0.07       0.000  ...        0.000       0.000   
3   1.45        0.0        1.00       0.000  ...        0.000       0.000   

SARMENT_45  SARMENT_46  SARMENT_47  SARMENT_48  SARMENT_49  \
0       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000   
1      13.222      12.241       4.909      25.068      12.496   
2       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000   
3       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000       0.000   

                      geometry  etat  teta  
0  POINT (-122.4301775 38.5597965)     g  None  
1  POINT (-122.4297791 38.5603706)     g  None  
2  POINT (-122.429778 38.5603719)     g  None  
3  POINT (-122.4297799 38.5603703)     g  None
```

Somebody have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print the dataframe head, Pandas may truncate the representations of longitude and latitude to fit your display. That's all. The data itself isn't truncated.

Changing the display precision in Pandas changes the display precision in GeoPandas as well. The actual stored values are unaffected.

```
pd.set_option('precision', 16)
```

This doesn't seem to work for the geometry column itself but you will see the extra precision in the longitude and latitude columns you created.